# Activemq cluster of embedded brokers and failover consumers

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, cluster-computing

### Environment

- There is an existing software with propietary way of clustering, which should be moved to use JMS
- The customer do not want to pay for setting up and mainaining a
  messaging system, so it can be used ONLY if I can embedd the whole
  messaging into the existing virtual machines
- Broker instances and consumers should be in the same JVM. Consumers
  should be able to connect to remote broker in failover situations, since all consumers no matter in which JVM will they run, should have ONE input queue.
- it would be nice if the consumers would use direct method calls to
  communicate with local broker

### Demo Project

I have created a really simple demo (eclipse) project with ActiveMQ + Maven + Spring (the whole project is at http://www.woofiles.com/dl-279452-fOcsWkcm-activemq.zip). If you try it, change the dataDirectory of activemq, since it is a wired absolute path till now.

I try to start up a broker from spring, and also a set of consumers. See Spring config below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK" />
    </bean>
        <bean id="embeddedBroker" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService"
            destroy-method="stop" init-method="start" >
            <property name="brokerName" value="conversion" />
            <property name="dataDirectory"
                value="c:\eclipseWithMaven\activemq\working\conversion" />
            <property name="schedulerSupport" value="false" />
            <property name="transportConnectorURIs">
                <list>
                    <value>tcp://127.0.0.1:600${idOfClusterNode}</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="managementContext">
                <bean class="org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext">
                    <property name="connectorPort" value="201${idOfClusterNode}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

    <!-- depends-on see why at http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html -->
    <!--depends-on="embeddedBroker" -->
    <bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" depends-on="embeddedBroker">
        <property name="brokerURL">
            <value>failover:(vm:/conversion,tcp://127.0.0.1:6001,tcp://127.0.0.1:6002)</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
        p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsFactory" p:sessionCacheSize="10" />
    <bean id="container"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="conversion" />
        <property name="destination" ref="conversionInputQueue" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="conversionInputQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="conversionInputQueue" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="conversion" class="activemq.Conversion"
        p:clusterId="${idOfClusterNode}" />
</beans>
```

I simply try to start up one or two instances of the activemq.ConversionDemo class with different parameters used by spring & log4j config. The environment entries of the run config looks like this:

- Instance 1 : -DidOfClusterNode=1 -DidOfOtherClusterNode=2 -DlogFile=conversion1.log
- Instance 2: -DidOfClusterNode=2 -DidOfOtherClusterNode=1
  -DlogFile=conversion2.log

If I start up one instance, it is fine. If two is running the following problems occoured:

- The second broker will not start up at all. It says it does not have the lock. Its fine, but I supposed, it just starts up a thread asynchronously, and will give back the control to spring. But it seems, that it wont let spring to continue.
- SimpleMessageListenerContainer also seems like holding the control
  over spring till all consumers are started.

### What I want

- I want to meet the requirements above
- I think I have to start up both brokers and consumers asynchronously,
  which I cannot really do in spring with this config
- It would be nice to have real load balancing between brokers. It seems, that ActiveMQ    is prepared only for failover.
- If my needs cannot be satisfied by    ActiveMQ, please recommend
  other free solution.

If you need further info, just let me know.

## EDIT

I think ActiveMQ supports my needs, I just need to understand "network of brokers". So I guess I have to have two filestore, and a network from my two brokers.

Comment: Do you really need network of brokers? Do you need to have multiple brokers for your consumers to connect to or you need two of them only for failover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you point 2 brokers at the same file store, then the first one will get the lock and the 2nd will block until the lock is released...this is a [shared file system master/slave](http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html) setup

if you want an active/active setup, then you'll need to use separate file stores and wire them together as a [network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

Comment: Yeah, but in this case there is two shortcoming: a message is exactly at one broker one time. So if a broker fails, the messages stuck at it. Otherwise, you are right. I will take this risk during designing my system, and I will use network of brokers.

Comment: agreed on the stuck messages...not a fan of this setup myself either

Comment: another option is to use network of brokers along with master/slave setup...see this article for details (http://tmielke.blogspot.com/2011/09/activemq-network-bridge-to-masterslave.html)